# Pandas to risk adjust surgery data - how to pass a list for 20,000 patients?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am a surgeon trying to use [hcuppy](https://github.com/yubin-park/hcuppy) to risk adjust surgical operation data. I have a pandas dataframe - 500k records and 56 columns.  Calling the adjustment module (elixhauser) expects a list of diagnostic codes and returns a weighted result for risk adjustment related to the diagnostic code.

eg

```
In[] : from hcuppy.elixhauser import ElixhauserEngine
In[] : ee = ElixhauserEngine()
In[] : out = ee.get_elixhauser(["C711"])

In [] : out
Out[]: {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mrtlt_scr': 7}
```

So that's good, I get the risk adjustment for having a brain tumour. However I have up to 20 diagnoses for each patient and would like to run the conversion on each diagnosis for cohorts of patients with up to 20,000 patients. At the moment I am limiting it to eg just 4 as below.

```
df.iloc[0:10, 7:11]

    DIAG_02 DIAG_03 DIAG_04 DIAG_05
0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   M7962   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   G800    Q798    NaN     NaN
3   G992-A  M4720D  G551-A  F101-
4   I10X    NaN     NaN     NaN
5   G971    G35X    Z881    N390
6   Z864-   NaN     NaN     NaN
7   F329    NaN     NaN     NaN
8   Z992-   E669-   K219-   I10X-
9   M510    G992    M4806   I10X
```

if I pass

```
out = ee.get_elixhauser([df.iloc[0:, 7:11]])
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-83647b38b5dc> in <module>
----> 1 out = ee.get_elixhauser([df.iloc[0:, 6:11]])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hcuppy/elixhauser.py in get_elixhauser(self, dx_lst)
     93             dx_lst = [dx_lst]
     94 
---> 95         dx_set = {dx.strip().upper().replace(".","") for dx in dx_lst}
     96         rawgrp_lst = [grp for grp in {search(dx) for dx in dx_set}
     97                         if grp not in {"", "NONE"}]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hcuppy/elixhauser.py in <setcomp>(.0)
     93             dx_lst = [dx_lst]
     94 
---> 95         dx_set = {dx.strip().upper().replace(".","") for dx in dx_lst}
     96         rawgrp_lst = [grp for grp in {search(dx) for dx in dx_set}
     97                         if grp not in {"", "NONE"}]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5128             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5129                 return self[name]
-> 5130             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5131 
   5132     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I was hoping to add the risk adjustment output as separate columns. As you can see I am very much a novice so need simple solutions.

**update** in light of parfait comments below.

Running

```
def clean_get_elixhauser(val):
  try:
     result = ee.get_elixhauser(val)
  except Exception as e:
     result = e             # RETURN EXCEPTION MESSAGE - ADJUST AS NEEDED

  return result if pd.isnull(val) else float('nan')

new_df = df.iloc[0:10, 7:11].copy().applymap(clean_get_elixhauser)
```

on the same dataframe returns,

```
DIAG_02 DIAG_03 DIAG_04 DIAG_05
0   'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
1   NaN 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
2   NaN NaN 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
7   NaN 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip' 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
8   NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

So, where I have NaN in the original dataframe -  'float' object has no attribute 'strip' is returned and where I have a code I get NaN. I am not sure what is happening here.

Comment: You can always use `for` loop for each column and run the function on it. Then concat the result into a single data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ee.get_elixhauser` is not a method that receives a whole data frame or array as an input parameter but does receive a scalar value, you will need to run method across every element of the data frame. Therefore, consider [**`DataFrame.applymap`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) assuming all data frame elements are the same type. Also, to avoid issues with assigning by slices due to `iloc`, use `copy()` before calling method.

```py
new_df = df.iloc[0:10, 7:11].copy().applymap(ee.get_elixhauser)
```

Additionally, you may need to handle `NaN`s and if `ee.get_elixhauser` raises an exception:

```
def clean_get_elixhauser(val):
  try:
     result = ee.get_elixhauser([val]) 
  except Exception as e:
     result = e             # RETURN EXCEPTION MESSAGE - ADJUST AS NEEDED

  return result if pd.notnull(val) else float('nan')

new_df = df.iloc[0:10, 7:11].copy().applymap(clean_get_elixhauser)
```

An additional challenge is that the method returns a dictionary which will be mapped as new elements in returned data frame. (Note: below does not use actual module `hcuppy.elixhauser` call but the posted result by OP for demonstration to avoid installing a module on my end).

```
def demo_get_elixhauser(val):
  result = {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mrtlt_scr': 7}

  return result if pd.notnull(val) else float('nan')

new_df = df.applymap(demo_get_elixhauser)

new_df
#                                              DIAG_02  ...                                            DIAG_05
# 0                                                NaN  ...                                                NaN
# 1  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...                                                NaN
# 2  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...                                                NaN
# 3  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...
# 4  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...                                                NaN
# 5  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...
# 6  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...                                                NaN
# 7  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...                                                NaN
# 8  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...
# 9  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...  ...  {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mr...
```

To fix, you can retrieve one element of returned dictionary by adjusting user defined method

```py
def clean_get_elixhauser(val):
  result = {'cmrbdt_lst': ['TUMOR'], 'rdmsn_scr': 15, 'mrtlt_scr': 7}

  return result['mrtlt_scr'] if pd.notnull(val) else float('nan')

mrtlt_df = df.applymap(clean_get_elixhauser)
  
mrtlt_df
#    DIAG_02  DIAG_03  DIAG_04  DIAG_05
# 0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
# 1      7.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
# 2      7.0      7.0      NaN      NaN
# 3      7.0      7.0      7.0      7.0
# 4      7.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
# 5      7.0      7.0      7.0      7.0
# 6      7.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
# 7      7.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
# 8      7.0      7.0      7.0      7.0
# 9      7.0      7.0      7.0      7.0
```

Comment: Thank you for all this. It is testing my capabilities in python , possibly not helped by limitations of the original method. I have tried your first step above and put the results in an addendum to the  original post.

Comment: On reviewing the data I think the cohorts of patients will be between 1000- 20,0000 so the for loop or iter suggestions may be acceptable even though they are slow.

Comment: Just realized you have to pass values into `ee.get_elixhauser()` as a list. Also, your return should check `pd.notnull` (not `pd.isnull`), so I had it reversed. See edit.

Comment: I think, having cleaned up the data I am getting somewhere thanks. Will take me a while to get my ehad round it. cheers